# Loop that pulls from list and adds together

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am nearing the completion of my program (i think) and my last part is creating a better loop that will take a list and purchase the items from the list in sequence until it runs out of money. While it is purchasing it will add together the values and then display it like

```
import random

money = input('Total money: ')
mi = int(money)

Food = ['Taco', 'Burrito', 'Nacho']
Price = [6, 4, 2]
Dict = {f:p for (f, p) in zip(Food, Price)}

while mi >= 0:
    RFS = random.sample(Food, 1)[0]
    cost = Dict[RFS]
    mi = mi - cost
    print("item: {} cost: {} money you have: {} ".format(RFS,cost,mi))
```

- Taco x2
- Burrito x3
- Nacho x1

Comment: I could not fully understand what exactly you are asking for. Do you want to optimize the loop you have, or facing a problem with it ?

Comment: I need it modified from what it currently does. It currently draws randomly from the list, "purchases" the item and then stop when the money runs out.

I need it to instead of randomly, sequentially purchase the items going from like 1st to last on the list. And if more money is left over repeat the process until none is left.

But it has to store how many times it purchased a property so say it purchases Taco 5 times, I need it to display Taco: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you did not want the random to be part of your code instead you wanted it to be sequentially. Following code should work for your requirement.

```
from collections import Counter
money = input('Total money: ')
mi = int(money)
Food = ['Taco', 'Burrito', 'Nacho']
Price = [6, 4, 2]
#Dict = {f:p for (f, p) in zip(Food, Price)}
purchase_ls = []
while mi >= min(Price):    
    for aFood in Food:
        if mi < int(Price[Food.index(aFood)]):
            continue
        purchase_ls.append(aFood)
        cost = int(Price[Food.index(aFood)])
        mi = mi - cost
        print("item: {} cost: {} money you have: {} ".format(aFood,cost,mi))  
        if mi <= 0:
            break         
print(dict(Counter(purchase_ls)))
```

Output:

```
Total money: 22
item: Taco cost: 6 money you have: 16 
item: Burrito cost: 4 money you have: 12 
item: Nacho cost: 2 money you have: 10 
item: Taco cost: 6 money you have: 4 
item: Burrito cost: 4 money you have: 0 
{'Taco': 2, 'Burrito': 2, 'Nacho': 1}

Total money: 20
item: Taco cost: 6 money you have: 14 
item: Burrito cost: 4 money you have: 10 
item: Nacho cost: 2 money you have: 8 
item: Taco cost: 6 money you have: 2 
item: Nacho cost: 2 money you have: 0 
{'Taco': 2, 'Burrito': 1, 'Nacho': 2}

Total money: 10
item: Taco cost: 6 money you have: 4 
item: Burrito cost: 4 money you have: 0 
{'Taco': 1, 'Burrito': 1}
```

Comment: This is currently what I am failing at doing https://i.imgur.com/WO4IKsj.png

I want it to sequentially choose the options in S, purchase them and then after purchasing is completed multiply the "You have 5 Tacos" part by the Value. I don't need it to display the cost of the purchases, i just need it to display the output of like HP: +25 (5 Tacos)
MP: +4 (4 Burritos)
AP: +3 (3 Nachos)

Comment: I am having trouble with a new loop do you think you could assist me? @OraAff

Comment: Currently, I am at work where I have only limited access yo Python. Provide the details of the problem you are experiencing in the new loop. Let me take a look at it. Honestly, I would suggest that if it is a new problem, post a new question so that someone else can help you out if I can't.

Comment: My loop isn't sequencing. It just purchases all of the first one until it can't then goes to the next option it can instead of buying 1 [0] then 1[1] etc... here is a pastebin of the loop in question https://pastebin.com/Gk4g1Emj

Comment: Provide me the values of S, CP and CostDic

Comment: `S = [HP,MP,AP]`  
`CP = input('Total CP: ')`  
`MasterStatList = ['HP', 'MP', 'AP', 'MAP', 'DEF', 'MDEF', 'ACC', 'MACC', 'EVA', 'RES', 'CRIT', 'SPD', 'STR', 'VIT', 'AGI', 'MAG', 'SPR', 'Special Ability']`  
`MasterStatCost = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 15, 15, 20, 20, 50, 35, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100]`  
`CostDic = {Li: Prop for (Li, Prop) in zip(MasterStatList, MasterStatCost)}`  

Its supposed to go through S which is a list that can be any of MasterStatList, I just hardplaced the list variables. But the loop is supposed to go through S in sequence so it starts by buying HP then MP then AP and

Comment: if there is anymore CP left then it will start at the top of the list again and repeat until there is no more.

Comment: 1. You need to remove the random function from your code.
2. Your counter is not moving to second property in the list S that is after purchasing HP it is not moving to MP and AP and so on because your For Loop is outside of While loop. 
3. Your While loop should be outside and For loop should be inside it. Check the code I posted above.

Comment: I found a way to make it work as my loop currently was! I just had to manually make it move over to the next variable at the end of the loop XD

Answer (score 0):

You can add a dictionary that keeps a total of what is purchased, then when there isn't enough money left to purchase any additional items it will be converted into "change".

```
import random

money = input('Total money: ')
mi = int(money)

Food = ['Taco', 'Burrito', 'Nacho']
Price = [6, 4, 2]
Dict = {f:p for (f, p) in zip(Food, Price)}

totals = {'Taco': 0, 'Burrito': 0, 'Nacho': 0, 'Change': 0}

while mi > 0:
    RFS = random.sample(Food, 1)[0]
    cost = Dict[RFS]
    if cost <= mi:
        mi += - cost
        print("item: {} cost: {} money you have: {} ".format(RFS, cost, mi))
        totals[RFS] += 1
    elif all(i > mi for i in Price):
        totals['Change'] = mi
        break

print(totals)
```

**Example Output**:

```
Total money: 11
item: Nacho cost: 2 money you have: 9 
item: Taco cost: 6 money you have: 3 
item: Nacho cost: 2 money you have: 1 
{'Taco': 1, 'Burrito': 0, 'Nacho': 2, 'Change': 1}
```

Comment: I mean, i am attempting whichever way I can figure out first XD if you have some way to message besides on this I can easily show you what I am doing and need help with. I am struggling lol

My problem is what I am attempting is not as simple as what I showed i guess? I made two dictionaries based on the list where it will match the item to its price and value. Cause my loop is doing three things? Basically Purchase 5 Tacos store how many tacos have been purchased then multiply the amount purchased by the value to get say Taco: 25 instead of Taco: 5

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a simple code with loops to do the behavior you asked for. The code is :

```
import random

money = int(input('Total money: '))

Food = ['Taco', 'Burrito', 'Nacho']
Price = [6, 4, 2]
Dict = {f:p for (f, p) in zip(Food, Price)}
Purchases = {f:0 for f in Dict}

stop = False
while not stop:
    for i in Dict:
        cost = Dict[i]
        if money - cost < 0:
            stop = True
        else:
            money -= cost
            Purchases[i] += 1

print(Purchases)
```

In the code, I created a new dict called `Purchases` which holds the count of total purchases per element in the `Dict`. I used two loops, the outer `while` loops runs until we run out of money, and the inner for loops iterates over the elements of `Dict` sequentially. I also changed the checking behavior s.t. the user cannot buy items if the money amount is going to negative, and at that point the loop stops. The output is a dict and is in the format of

`{'Taco': 1, 'Burrito': 0, 'Nacho': 0}`

So I believe you can write your own printing loop to print the output in the way you desire.

Comment: Oh I am attempting! I think i forever looped it lol, gonna take me a long time to figure out how to implement this.

Comment: This code does not give the desired result. For Total Money: 4 the code gives output: {'Taco': 0, 'Burrito': 0, 'Nacho': 0} which is wrong.

Comment: Deleting the break line would solve that... I thought of it purchasing sequentially and that's why stopped the program

Comment: @B14d3r11 why did it forever looped ?

Comment: @B14d3r11 in the link, I don't see a part in the loop that edits `rarPopTotal` or `l`. Could that be the reason for the inf. loop, or is there an unseen part of the outer loop ?

Comment: That loop is the only new thing added to the code that error'd or has had any problems. And everything needed to make the loop is in the screenshot i think. Im just having a difficult time cause my brain is frying